# Does Ubuntu support the asus crosshair v formula Z motherboard?

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I have been trying to install ubuntu 15.04. I have no errors, and I can load the OS on the flash drive as well as see and play with all my windows drives on the system, but the partitioner freezes and times out.

I have a dual boot system working in my office on an old rampage 3 system, so it leads to me to believe it has something to do with UEFI, and the sata port driver configuration.

Comment: Are you using dynamic partitions in Windows? If so that may be the problem. Make sure that Windows is shut down fully (no fast start allowed).

Answer (score 1):

[This page on the Asus website](https://www.asus.com/websites/global/aboutasus/OS/Linux.pdf) says that your motherboard support Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I think this would be an acceptable answer if it definitively answered the question, but it doesn't.  Look more closely at the other distros in that sheet: Fedora 17 and openSUSE 12.1. In other words, the sheet is outdated. 12.04 was just the most recent release at the time; it doesn't mean that the motherboard in incompatible with newer releases. If anything it means it probably is ok with 15.04, since it's unlikely the kernel dropped support for that hardware.